# Shapeshift API always returns "No Withdrawal Address Specified" error

Tags: php, guzzle

I am using [Shape Shift API](https://info.shapeshift.io/api#api-7) for sending transaction with Guzzle. I am always getting the error given in title. My code given below:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$data   = [
    "amount"        => 1,
    "withdrawal"    => '0x23f016d7a8e408e5551ae7aa51b3fe1534165463',
    "pair"          => 'btc_eth',
    "returnAddress" => '12stJs8vZNuuVfjZSSzpLPA96quNissk1b'
];
$result = $client->post( 'https://shapeshift.io/shift', [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ],
    [ 'json' => $data ] );

print "<pre>";
print_r( $result->getBody()->getContents() );
print "</pre>";
```

Same parameters work fine when using in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the request wrong. The correct variant is with two parameters:

```
$result = $client->post('https://shapeshift.io/shift', ['json' => $data]);
```

Content type is configured automatically when you use [`json` option](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json).